# What is missing in my makefile?

Tags: c, makefile

I am trying to create my first makefile.  I tested my program by using the following commands:

```
Command 1: gcc -Wall -ggdb3 -std=c99 -o file1 file1.c -lm -lpthread -l
Command 2: gcc -Wall -ggdb3 -std=c99 -o file2 file2.c -lm -lpthread
```

Everything works great. Then I created a makefile (please see below).  I keep getting an error message. Can someone take a look at my code and give me a hint on what the problem is?

```
file2.o: In function `seed_primes':
file2.c:(.text+0x461): undefined reference to `sqrt'
file2.c:(.text+0x466): undefined reference to `sqrt'
file2:(.text+0x533): undefined reference to `sqrt'
file2.o: In function `create_threads':
file2.c:(.text+0x668): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
file2.c:(.text+0x6b5): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
file2.o: In function `next_seed':
file2.c:(.text+0x860): undefined reference to `sqrt'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [file2] Error 1
```

Here is my makefile:

```
CC=gcc
DEBUG=-ggdb3
CFLAGS=#(DEBUG) -Wall -lm -lpthread -lrt -l

PROGS=file1 file2 

all: $(PROGS) 

file1: file1.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o file1 file1.o 

file1.o: file1.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c file1.c     

file2: file2.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o file2 file2.o 

file2.o: file2.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c file2.c  

clean:
    rm -f $(PROGS) *.o *~
```

Comment: What does the `-l` option on its own do for you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've set CFLAGS to an empty string because of the `#` comment character (you probably intended to use a `$` instead).

You should not set libraries into `CFLAGS`; they belong in `LDLIBS`.

You don't need the `file1:` rule, the `file2:` rule, or the object file rules.

```
CC     = gcc
DEBUG  = -ggdb3
CFLAGS = $(DEBUG) -Wall
LDLIBS = -lm -lpthread -lrt -l

PROGS  = file1 file2 

all: $(PROGS) 

clean:
    rm -f $(PROGS) *.o *~
```

NB: `LDLIBS` and the related `LDFLAGS` are not 100% uniform across variants of `make`.  `LDFLAGS` should be used for library paths; `LDLIBS` is for the library names (`-lxyz` etc).

If you need different libraries for the two programs, you will need to create separate build rules (as you had originally), or use conditional macro assignments (GNU `make`).

Comment: Thank u so much for the tip!  I fixed my makefile. It created 2 executables.  But I got a warning saying - "icc: command line warning #10155: ignoring option '-l'; argument required". Is there something I need to add? (Note: I changed gcc to icc to make it compile in my school's server).

Comment: Oops, after I removed "-l" from the makefile, the warning disappear.  I run the executables...Everything seems to work fine.  I used -l earlier because when I run it in the terminal, I keep getting some kind of warning and it goes away after I add -l

Comment: I asked about the plain `-l` in the comments to the questions; I'd simply drop it and see whether that works; it probably will.  The `-l` flag is normally followed by a library 'name' (so `-lm` or `-l m`); with no argument following, it is asking the linker to link a library with no name, or something like that...hence the warning from `icc`.  So, remove the `-l` from `LDLIBS`.

Comment: Ah. Thanks for explaining it to me! You are a lot better than my professor.  I recognize your name. You gave me hints/help in some of the previous questions I asked here. I really want to say thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You put all of your flags in `CFLAGS` which makes them appear *before* the object files in the command line.  Notice that your test commands didn't do that.

Change your flags:

```
CFLAGS=$(DEBUG) -Wall 
LDFLAGS=-lm -lpthread -lrt
```

And then in the recipes:

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o file1 file1.o $(LDFLAGS)
```