# Please help me with the make file error in gcc compiler

Tags: c, linux, gcc

First of all : I am a newbee in linux.

2nd -- I have seen [What is missing in my makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18407917/what-is-missing-in-my-makefile)
but did not still get what is wrong with my make file. Though I am getting the same errors he was getting.
Error that I am getting after running the makefile:

```
    user@ubuntu:~/Documents/Myfiles/Adaptive Doppler$ make adaptiveav
    gcc -o adaptiveav simpsimaav.o findvel.o do_fft.o four1.o subdc.o do_peak_n.o -g
    simpsimaav.o: In function `main':
    /home/user/Documents/Myfiles/Adaptive Doppler/simpsimaav.c:179: undefined reference to `cos'
    /home/user/Documents/Myfiles/Adaptive Doppler/simpsimaav.c:180: undefined reference to `sin'
    /home/user/Documents/Myfiles/Adaptive Doppler/simpsimaav.c:299: undefined reference to `sin'
    /home/user/Documents/Myfiles/Adaptive Doppler/simpsimaav.c:299: undefined reference to `sin'
    /home/user/Documents/Myfiles/Adaptive Doppler/simpsimaav.c:299: undefined reference to `sin'
    /home/user/Documents/Myfiles/Adaptive Doppler/simpsimaav.c:325: undefined reference to `sqrt'
    /home/user/Documents/Myfiles/Adaptive Doppler/simpsimaav.c:325: undefined reference to `sqrt'
    /home/user/Documents/Myfiles/Adaptive Doppler/simpsimaav.c:326: undefined reference to `cos'
    /home/user/Documents/Myfiles/Adaptive Doppler/simpsimaav.c:327: undefined reference to `sin'
    simpsimaav.o: In function `rayleigh':
    /home/user/Documents/Myfiles/Adaptive Doppler/simpsimaav.c:418: undefined reference to `log'
    /home/user/Documents/Myfiles/Adaptive Doppler/simpsimaav.c:418: undefined reference to `sqrt'
    /home/user/Documents/Myfiles/Adaptive Doppler/simpsimaav.c:421: undefined reference to `sqrt'
    four1.o: In function `four1':
    /home/user/Documents/Myfiles/Adaptive Doppler/four1.c:47: undefined reference to `sin'
    /home/user/Documents/Myfiles/Adaptive Doppler/four1.c:49: undefined reference to `sin'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make: *** [adaptiveav] Error 1

-------------------------------------------------------------
```

My make file :

```
    OBJS= main.o do_fft.o find_m.o read_sig.o write_out.o allocin.o\
    getopts.o read_form.o read_bin.o optlist.o usage.o normalize.o \
    enquire.o init_fft.o subdc.o skip.o shortfile.o open_out.o \
    han_win.o getyn.o record.o do_mom.o frq_arry.o four1.o look_nfo.o\
    do_peak.o coefs_out.o do_smooth.o do_maxf.o accum.o pspect.o except.o\
    get_info.o open_in.o test_read.o getstr.o getint.o open_nfo.o line_flush.o \
    simpsim1.o


    # Note: these routines are found in Lib/lib.ar
    LIBOBJS= debug.c div_by.c getint.c getstr.c \
    init_ap.c look_nfo.c open_in.c open_nfo.c test_read.c

    # LIBS= -lm /usr/local/src/Cspect/Lib/lib.ar -lfpe
    LIBS = -lm

    CFLAGS= -g
    rtest: rtest.o realft.o four1.o
        gcc -o rtest rtest.o realft.o four1.o -lm $(CFLAGS)
    itest: itest.o realft.o four1.o
        gcc -o itest itest.o realft.o four1.o -lm $(CFLAGS)
    test: test.o four1.o
        gcc -o test test.o four1.o -lm $(CFLAGS)
    invtest: invtest.o four1.o
        gcc -o invtest invtest.o four1.o -lm $(CFLAGS)
    tabtest: test.o ffttab.o
        gcc -o test test.o ffttab.o -lm $(CFLAGS)

    cspect: ${OBJS}
        gcc -o cspect.exe ${OBJS} ${LIBS} ${CFLAGS}

    rdtest: rdtest.o read_form.o
        gcc -o rdtest rdtest.o read_form.o -g

    fttest: sine.o do_fft.o four1.o subdc.o do_peak.o
        gcc -o fttest sine.o do_fft.o four1.o subdc.o do_peak.o 

    adaptive: simpsima.o findvel.o do_fft.o four1.o subdc.o do_peak.o
        gcc -o adaptive simpsima.o findvel.o do_fft.o four1.o subdc.o do_peak.o -g

    notadaptive: simpsimna.o findvel.o do_fft.o four1.o subdc.o do_peak.o
        gcc -o notadaptive simpsimna.o findvel.o do_fft.o four1.o subdc.o do_peak.o -g

    adaptivevold:  simpsimavold.o findvel.o do_fft.o four1.o subdc.o do_peak.o
        gcc -o adaptivevold simpsimavold.o findvel.o do_fft.o four1.o subdc.o do_peak.o

    adaptivev:  simpsimav.o findvel.o do_fft.o four1.o subdc.o do_peak_n.o
        gcc -o adaptivev simpsimav.o findvel.o do_fft.o four1.o subdc.o do_peak_n.o -g


    notadaptivev: simpsimnav.o findvel.o do_fft.o four1.o subdc.o do_peak_n.o
        gcc -o notadaptivev simpsimnav.o findvel.o do_fft.o four1.o subdc.o do_peak_n.o -g


    adaptiveav:  simpsimaav.o findvel.o do_fft.o four1.o subdc.o do_peak_n.o
        gcc -o adaptiveav simpsimaav.o findvel.o do_fft.o four1.o subdc.o do_peak_n.o -g


    .c.o:
        gcc -c ${CFLAGS} $*.c

    #simpsim.o: simpsim.c
    #   gcc -c simpsim1.c

    : spect
    strip spect
    chmod 755 spect
    chgrp user spect
    mv spect /usr/local/bin
```

---

This is not the directory where my lib.ar is : Is it probably for this?

```
# LIBS= -lm /usr/local/src/Cspect/Lib/lib.ar -lfpe
LIBS = -lm"
```

and I dont want you to do my  works... just suggest me anything... or any useful website where they talk about these things...

I hope not to get rude comments just because I am new.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The undefined references are all math functions found in `libm.a`. The part with the `-lm` in the Makefile did not make it to the gcc command. Try adding `-lm` to the gcc command and it should work. Specifically, this

```
adaptiveav:  simpsimaav.o findvel.o do_fft.o four1.o subdc.o do_peak_n.o
        gcc -o adaptiveav simpsimaav.o findvel.o do_fft.o four1.o subdc.o do_peak_n.o -g
```

is missing a reference to `$(LIBS)` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
 adaptiveav:  simpsimaav.o findvel.o do_fft.o four1.o subdc.o do_peak_n.o
        gcc -o adaptiveav simpsimaav.o findvel.o do_fft.o four1.o subdc.o do_peak_n.o -g
```

As you can see the -lm switch isn't on that line. So the references to cos are unresolved.